# Binding array to directive variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to get an array into a template so I can use the individuals values thereof. My problem is that the attribute turns into a string once inside my template so it's no longer accessible as {{var[0]}} and that will instead return the first character of the "string", usually "["

Here is a simplified setup of the data:

```
"varForward": ["100", "1"],
"varBack": ["1", "100"]
```

Here is a simplified portion of the HTML file that interacts with that data:

```
<my-customer-vars value="{{varForward}}">
    </address-numbers>
<my-customer-vars value="{{varBack}}">
    </address-numbers>
```

and lastly here is a portion that is SUPPOSED to replace the custom tag with my own stuff:

```
directive('myCustomerVars', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            value: "@"
        },
        template:
        '<div>'+
          '<p class="body-text">Some stuff goes here</p>'+
          '<input type="text" name="firstinput" value="{{value[0]}}"> - '+
          '<input type="text" name="secondinput" value="{{value[1]}}">'+
        '</div>',
        replace: true
    }
});
```

So here I am, if I try using value[0] I get [  If I try to get value[1] I get " and so on. Is there any help on using arrays inside the template of a directive?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to change the "@" into "=" and to pass in the array without the {{ }}

like this:

```
<my-customer-vars value="varForward">
    </my-customer-vars>
<my-customer-vars value="varBack">
    </my-customer-vars>
```

directive:

```
directive('myCustomerVars', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            value: "="
        },
        template:
        '<div>'+
          '<p class="body-text">Some stuff goes here</p>'+
          '<input type="text" name="firstinput" value="{{value[0]}}"> - '+
          '<input type="text" name="secondinput" value="{{value[1]}}">'+
        '</div>',
        replace: true
    }
});
```

This is happening because every expression inside a directuve attribute defined by a @ gets evaluated as only as a string, and in the other way it gets evaluated as binding expression. (with 2 way binding, so be careful).

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect! I'm not completely comfortable with the scope variables, but that helped clear up a lot of questions I had, including how to use them.

Comment: Now that we're passing models instead of values, I suggest `model="varForward"` and then `scope: { model: '=' }`.

Comment: @ShaiRez Is this the best way to take the array and put it in a template?  I'm fairly new wondering if there are alternatives.

Comment: does this work as of 1.08 because it doesn't seem to be for me

Comment: Yep, it has not changed

Answer (score 16):

If you would prefer not creating an isolate scope in the directive (such as when creating custom validation directives) you could pass the array as:

```
<my-customer-vars model="varForward">
```

And then read the value in the linking function of the directive as:

```
directive('myCustomerVars', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            var myVars = scope[attrs.model]; // <--- took a time to figure out
            console.log(myVars);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @greg this reply is from a long time ago, I suppose about the time of Angular 1.1 or 1.2. Maybe it doesn't work anymore in newer versions. I don't use Angular anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to the reply of Danita, you will have to use `$eval` for fetching this scope variable:

Just change

```
var myVars = scope[attrs.model];
```

to

```
var myVars = scope.$eval(attrs.model);
```

Comment: Thanks. I wish this was better explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Just another perspective - if the problem is just managing an array of strings in angular application I would use one of the following (or any similar):

1. [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/)
2. [angular select2 with Tags mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2#using-simple-tagging-mode)
3. [ngList](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngList)

Unless you are practicing creating your own angular directives (then just ignore my answer)