# Passing array via attribute to AngularJS directive

Tags: arrays, parsing, angularjs, attributes, directive

I'm currently having a problem when passing an array to a directive via an attribute of that directive. I can read it as a String but i need it as an array so this is what i came up with but it doesn't work. Help anyone? thks in advance

Javascript::

```
app.directive('post', function($parse){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope:{
            title: "@",
            author: "@",
            content: "@",
            cover: "@",
            date: "@"
        },
        templateUrl: 'components/postComponent.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.tags = $parse(attrs.tags)
        }
    }
}
```

HTML::

```
<post title="sample title" tags="['HTML5', 'AngularJS', 'Javascript']" ... >
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you're accessing this array from your scope, i.e. loaded in a controller, you can just pass the name of the variable:

[Binding array to directive variable in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695792/binding-array-to-directive-variable-in-angularjs)

**Directive:**

```
scope:{
        title: "@",
        author: "@",
        content: "@",
        cover: "@",
        date: "@",
        tags: "="
    },
```

**Template:**

```
<post title="sample title" tags="arrayName" ... >
```

Comment: What if it is an inline array: `tags="[1 ,2 ,3]"` ?  Edit: I found my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20811527/3328979

Comment: tags is undefined when i do `console.log(scope.tags)`. what could be wrong

Answer (score 4):

you can also have to use $scope instead of attrs. then you will get array object, otherwise you will get an string.

```
     scope:{
            title: "@",
            author: "@",
            content: "@",
            cover: "@",
            date: "@",
            tags: "="
        },


link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.tags = scope.tags
        }
```