# angularjs pass newly created array in attribute to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've created this fiddle to show my issue...

http://jsfiddle.net/dQDtw/

I'm passing a newly created array to a directive, and everything is working out just fine.  However, I'm getting an error in the console window indicating:

`Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

Any thoughts on what I need to massage to clean this up?  I'd like to be able to reuse the directive without the need to update the controller.

Here is the html

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <test-dir fam-people='[1,4,6]'> </test-dir>
    <test-dir fam-people='[2,1,0]'> </test-dir>
</body>
```

Here is the JS.

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
myApp.directive('testDir', function() {
            return { restrict: 'E'
                   , scope: { famPeople: '=famPeople' }
                   , template: "<ol> <li ng-repeat='p in famPeople'> {{p}}"
                   };
    });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That error is because your directive is not able to interpret the array as an array, Try this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl1">
    <test-dir fam-people='people'> </test-dir>

</body>



var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('testDir', function() {
                return { restrict: 'E'
                       , scope: { famPeople: '=' }
                       , template: "<ol> <li ng-repeat='p in famPeople'> {{p}}"
                       };
        });
```

Controller and directive:

```
myApp.controller("ctrl1",function($scope){
$scope.people=[1,4,6];
});
```

EDIT

or you could pass it in as an attribute and parse it to an array:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" >
    <test-dir fam-people='[1,4,6]'> </test-dir>

</body>
```

Directive:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('testDir', function() {
                return { restrict: 'E', 
                        //scope: { famPeople: '=' },
                       template: "<ol> <li ng-repeat='p in people track by $index'> {{p}}",
                        link:function(scope, element, attrs){
                      scope.people=JSON.parse(attrs.famPeople);
                        }
                       };
        });
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5YK9b/).

Comment: Thanks, that would probably work.  But I'd like to be able to reuse the directive without updates to a controller.  I've updated my questions to be more specific

Comment: Thanks, I think the edit is more in line with what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 14):

JSON parse doesn't work as effective when the array contains string.

For example:

```
<file-handler fh-services="['BOX','DROPBOX']"></file-handler>
```

In the directive you can use `scope.$eval` to convert what appears in the attribute to an array.

```
scope.$eval(attrs.fhServices)
```

Comment: I agree that this looks like the more proper solution when you aren't using data-binding.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for a requirement I was working on. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <test-dir fam-people='1;4;6'> </test-dir>
    <test-dir fam-people='2;1;0'> </test-dir>
</body>
```

and

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.directive('testDir', function() {
                return { restrict: 'E', 
                        //scope: { famPeople: '=' },
                       template: "<ol> <li ng-repeat='p in people track by $index'> {{p}}",
                        link:function(scope, element, attrs){
                      scope.people= attrs.famPeople.split(';');
                        }
                       };
        });
```

cleanest solution?