# Pass in array of values to Directive

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4.2 for an old app. It is mixed with Angular. I need to display a map of locations returned from Laravel.

I am using an Angular directive on a `blade` template to do this.

I need to pass Laravel values into the directive so they can be used. I saw you can pass an array in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290782/passing-array-via-attribute-to-angularjs-directive), but am not sure how to do it with Laravel blade values.

Note: Since blade uses `{{ }}` for interpolation, I have told Angular to change its interpolation:

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
```

Laravel blade template: `$locations` is a `blade` variable:

```
<fz-map locations="{{$locations}}"></fz-map>
```

Directive:

```
( function( ng, app ) {

    'use strict';

    app.directive( 'fzMap', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope : {
                locations : '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                console.log('loc', scope.locations);
                scope.Template = '/directive_html/map.html';
            },
            template: "<div ng-include='Template'></div>"
        };
    } ]);
} )( angular, myApp );
```

Angular error: `Unexpected end of expression: [{`

Comment: `locations : '='` in directive means you are binding to an angular model in parent of the directive. Why can't you make api request for that data?

Comment: I don't know much about blade -- is it rendered client-side or server-side?  As @charlietfl points out, you can only two-way bind to a property in an angular scope.  If Blade renders first, you might be able to send the data one-way using '@' or get it into an angular $scope property using `ng-init='locations = {{$locations}}'`.  Just some thoughts...If Angular renders first, then this of course won't work.