# Attribute value being parsed as string in directive despite using "="

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm trying to create a custom directive and send an array into it to create a dynamic template. I've looked at these two questions:

[Binding array to directive variable in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695792/binding-array-to-directive-variable-in-angularjs)

[Passing array via attribute to AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290782/passing-array-via-attribute-to-angularjs-directive)

I'm using the same code basically but when I console log the `tAttrs` it only shows tags as `"testArray"` instead of `Array(2)` as it would be should the `tags="testArray"` be interpreted correctly.

From what I can see I haven't done anything wrong here so it's kinda driving me to insanity why it's not working.

Can someone point out why this isn't working as expected?

The controller containing the array:

```
forumApp.controller('profileCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.testArray = ['displayName', 'email'];
}
```

The directive markup:

```
<error tags="testArray"></error>
```

And the directive:

```
forumApp.directive('error', [function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            tags: "="
        },
        template: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            console.log(tAttrs);
            return "<div ng-if='row.model === " + tAttrs.tags[0] + "'>Hello world</div>";
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: There are problems with your directive. First: attributes are not the right way to get scope values. Second: you are creating isolate scope and you are probably using values from the parent scope(row).

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları Give me suggestion on how to change it then, and from the questions I included it appears that it's indeed the way to do it? Makes me a bit confused.

Comment: You can move the ng-if outside the directive: `<error ng-if="row.model === testArray[0]"></error>`. Then you wouldn't need to create an isolate scope in your directive.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları Not sure if that would work with the complete example, because I've got additional elements within the div that also uses if-statements.

Comment: You can't access parent scope elements in an isolated scope. Are you aware of that? `row` is not defined in the directive scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to put the array in isolated scope, you don't need `tAttrs` anymore:

```
template: function(tElement) {
            return "<div ng-if='row.model === " + tags[0] + "'>Hello world</div>";
        }
```

The above template will look for `tags` on the isolated scope.  `tAttrs` was pulling the *raw* attribute off of the element.